# Selecting parts of a raster within certain parameters in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, intersection

I am new to ArcGIS Pro and trying to learn how to do analysis with rasters. I have two raster datasets: one with an elevation profile of a US state, and another showing land use. I am trying to create a new raster that shows an intersection between land use of a specific category and elevation <1000. In ArcGIS Pro, what tool should I use to create the new raster?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [Con](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/con-.htm) (Conditional) tool, either standalone or within the [Raster Calculator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/raster-calculator.htm) to put together a statement roughly like Con(elevation<1000 AND landuse==X, true_output, false output). There are a handful of different ways you can phrase the same query depending on which tool you use, so treat my syntax with a grain of salt. This [Esri blog post](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/analytics/analytics/performing-analysis-with-the-con-tool/) gives a far more in depth answer on how to use a complex statement within the Con tool for a very similar kind of habitat/suitability question.